How do I create a dropdown list of available fonts on an Access form?
I have an Access database that was put together without any standards.  The textboxes on different forms are in different fonts.  the header backgrounds are different, etc...
I want to create a 'Format Form'.  This form would include a font name button that lists all of the available fonts.  I want to use the same button that is used in microsoft programs.
The selection would be used to change all of the textboxes on all of the forms to that font.
I have the code to change all of the textboxes on all of the forms.  I just need to know if there is a way to get the control onto a form.
I can hard code a list, but that won't work on a machine with different fonts.
If there is a way access the fonts I can create my own list, but I would rather use an exiting control

Google: "Access VBA font list" - https://www.devhut.net/vba-list-fonts/

A solution was given in comments, but another approach is to get them from MS Word. You can store them in a local table for easy access.
Sub T()
    On Error GoTo Trap
    
    Dim wd As Object
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    
    Dim fontName As Variant
    For Each fontName In wd.FontNames
        Debug.Print fontName 
    Next
    
Leave:
   If Not wd Is Nothing Then wd.Quit
   Exit Sub
   
Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub


I got strange results.
The list includes 1402 fonts.  Most of them do not appear in the Word drop down
(for example Athiti).
To make it stranger, when I look at wd.fontnames in the VBA debugger it only lists 256 fonts.
This is the code
Public Sub GetFonts(strTableName As String)
    On Error GoTo Error_Handler
    
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim wd As Object
    
    Dim Name As Variant
    Dim counter As Integer: counter = 0

    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strTableName)
    
    With rs
        .MoveFirst
        For Each Name In wd.FontNames
            If .EOF Then
                .AddNew
                .Update
                .MoveLast
            End If
            .Edit
            !fontName = Name
            counter = counter + 1
            Debug.Print "counter " & counter

            Pos = InStr(Name, "Athiti")
            If Pos > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "one of the wierd ones"
            End If
        Next
    End With
        
Error_Handler_Exit:
    closeRS rs
    Set db = Nothing
    If Not wd Is Nothing Then wd.Quit
    Exit Sub
    
Error_Handler:
    ErrorMessage "Helper Format - GetFonts"
    GoTo Error_Handler_Exit
End Sub

What am i missing?strong text
